# Starting a new project with Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php, project-management, octobercms

Im beginning a new project with Laravel 4 / 5 (done this many times).

I dont want to re-write the wheel setting up admin interfaces and user authentication.

Is it wise to use something like OctoberCMS and pull it part to my own ends?

Why I would do this:

- I want extensive CMS functionality
- I want a nice user interface
- I dont want to code all that!

Comment: October has a long way to go IMO.  If you use October expect that you will still need to write some (a lot) of code to get what you want.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator

Answer (score 3):

I have dabbled with the october CMS, and it's really great (as a cms) for someone like a front end dev (rather than say, a generic client who wants to just update content).

A lot of work has been put into the CMS, and to use it effectively you will be extending the October CMS which means doing things the "October way" assuming you want to tie most of your added functionality into some sort of user interface.

If you are ok with learning the ins and outs of October - then it seems like in the long run it will be of benefit.

If you don't go with October - there aren't many alternatives ([packages] which I have come across) which provide a simple foundation and have been updated recently - having said that the core of wardrobe might be something to look into: https://github.com/wardrobecms/core

As for roles/auth - take a look at Entrust (https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) and Confide - I have used them together in the past and found them functional and easy to use.

(I have no affiliation with any of the packages mentioned above)